# Removing a 3 decimal point limit

Tags: javascript, khan-academy

I've recently been making a calculator, and it was going fine until I ran into the issue where, when I add a decimal point, it makes it so I can only have 3 decimal points, rather then being able to do all the rest of the digits.

So I guess the main thing I'm asking, is there anyway to remove the thing that seems to restrict the number of decimal points, unless `Number(string)` and `parseFloat(string)` automatically restricts to 3 decimal points, then I have no idea what's wrong

I'm currently using 3 main functions for this:

```
var RemoveDigit = function(int) {
    var string = int.toString();
    
    return IsNumber(parseFloat(string.slice(0, string.length-1) + "" + string.slice(string.length)));
};//removes a digit

var convert = function(int1, int2) {
    var int = int1.toString()+int2.toString();
    return parseFloat(int);
};//makes it go to the next digit rather then just adding to the previous number

function insertDecimal(int) {
    var string = int.toString();
    return (string = string + ".");
}//inserts decimal
```

and then I go about doing the math and such, but I'd really like it if it wouldn't restrict the number of digits after the decimal.

Comment: Can you add some code snippet to show what you currently have and what output you want/expect? Also try adding a tag to the question containing the programming language you use, people will be able to locate your question much better that way.

Comment: `parseFloat("0.12345")` and `Number("0.12345")` return `0.12345` so your assumptions are indeed wrong and you need to provide us more context.

Comment: do you just want me to send the ENTIRE thing? it's only like 200 lines

Comment: No, as per the [posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask) you should reduce your code to [mcve] form, and then post _that_ instead. (yes, that's going to be a little bit of work, but almost always while doing that work you end up discovering the problem on your own, suddenly making your post to SO not necessary anymore)